# Drawing onto a picturebox in a Windows Form from a different class

Tags: c#, winforms

In my code, I have a `PictureBox` with a background picture. I used to draw a rectangle over it using

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Turquoise, 2);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(600, 300, 5, 5);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, r);
    p.Dispose();
}
```

Now, that I know I will need to do a lot of things with these rectangles and create them dynamically, I have created a class for them, with a constructor looking like this:

```
public MyRectangles(int x, int y)
{
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Turquoise, 2);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, 5, 5);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, r);
    p.Dispose();
}
```

The problem is, that the `e` in `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, r);` does not exist here. It makes sense, I understand why, however, I dont know what to replace it with, to draw on the same picturebox again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing the Graphics object:

```
public MyRectangles(Graphics g, int x, int y)
{
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Turquoise, 2);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, 5, 5);
    g.DrawRectangle(p, r);
    p.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: What exactly should I pass as g? The PictureBox itself?

Comment: @MarekBuchtela From the PictureBox paint event, pass the `e.Graphics`.

Comment: Yeah, its my fault, should have stated this right in the question above - I wont be calling this from the paint event, but perhaps after pressing a button or something, so I am not quite sure how to get the `e.Graphics` there.

Comment: You still call it from the paint event.  Have your button call `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` to have the paint event fired off.